# pymc3: How to implement a deterministic operation that requires iteration?

Tags: theano, pymc3

For the sake of this question, I am attempting to port a pymc2 example from [this blog post](https://healthyalgorithms.com/2010/10/19/mcmc-in-python-how-to-stick-a-statistical-model-on-a-system-dynamics-model-in-pymc/), the bit of interest being:

```py
## SI model

from pymc import *
from numpy import *

#observed data
T = 10
susceptible_data = array([999,997,996,994,993,992,990,989,986,984])
infected_data = array([1,2,5,6,7,8,9,11,13,15])

# stochastic priors
beta = Uniform('beta', 0., 40., value=1.)
gamma = Uniform('gamma', 0., 1., value=.001)
SI_0 = Uninformative('SI_0', value=[999., 1.])

# deterministic compartmental model
@deterministic
def SI(SI_0=SI_0, beta=beta, gamma=gamma):
    S = zeros(T)
    I = zeros(T)
    S[0] = SI_0[0]
    I[0] = SI_0[1]
    for i in range(1,T):
        S[i] = S[i-1] - 0.05*beta*S[i-1]*I[i-1]/(S[i-1]+I[i-1])
        I[i] = max(0., I[i-1] + 0.05*beta*S[i-1]*I[i-1]/(S[i-1]+I[i-1]) - gamma*I[i-1])
    return S, I
S = Lambda('S', lambda SI=SI: SI[0])
I = Lambda('I', lambda SI=SI: SI[1])

# data likelihood
A = Poisson('A', mu=S, value=susceptible_data, observed=True)
B = Poisson('B', mu=I, value=infected_data, observed=True)
```

The part that I am stuck with is that the author has used a plain-old (backwards) difference method with a fixed step size of 0.05 to simulate `S` and `I` at each step, very sensible.

However, I cannot figure out a way to do this in pymc3 since said simulation requires running the (backwards) difference approximation over the array, which is not something that I can seem to figure out how to do in pymc3.

For example, my first approximation was to do:

```py
import numpy as np
import pymc3 as pm
import theano

t = 10

susceptible_data = array([999,997,996,994,993,992,990,989,986,984])
infected_data = array([1,2,5,6,7,8,9,11,13,15])


def si_bdiff(si_0, beta, gamma):
    s = np.zeros(t, dtype=theano.config.floatX)
    f = np.zeros(t, dtype=theano.config.floatX)

    s[0] = si_0[0]
    f[0] = si_0[1]

    for i in range(1,t):
        s[i] = s[i-1] - 0.05 * beta * s[i-1] * f[i-1] / (s[i-1] + f[i-1])
        f[i] = max(0., f[i-1] + 0.05 * beta * s[i-1] * f[i-1] / (s[i-1] + f[i-1]) - gamma * f[i-1])
    return s, f


with pm.Model() as model:
    beta = pm.Uniform('beta', lower=0, upper=40)
    gamma = pm.Uniform('gamma', lower=0, upper=1)
    si_0 = pm.Flat('SI_0', shape=2)

    s, f = pm.Deterministic('si', si_bdiff(si_0, beta, gamma))

    # data likelihood
    A = pm.Poisson('A', mu=s, observed=susceptible_data)
    B = pm.Poisson('B', mu=f, observed=infected_data)

    trace1 = pm.sample(100000, tune=50000, cores=4, init='advi')
```

which, of course, failed miserably. I have been fiddling around with a number of aspects with this problem, but the above version holds my key problem, in that I don't know how to use `pm.Deterministic` in this manner, specifically to be able to iterate over (something?) and return what is basically a pair of arrays.

Thanks!

**EDIT**

This is driving me crazy, I'm so close but...

Here is the guts of my current code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pymc3 as pm

import theano
import theano.tensor as tt
import theano.tests.unittest_tools

from scipy.optimize import fsolve


def dSdt(Scur, Icur, beta):
    N = Icur + Scur
    eqn = -beta * Scur * Icur / N
    return eqn

def dIdt(Scur, Icur, beta, gamma):
    N = Icur + Scur
    eqn = beta * Scur * Icur / N - gamma * Icur
    return eqn

def bkwd_euler(cur, prev, beta, gamma, h):
    Scur, Icur = cur
    Sprev, Iprev = prev
    N = Scur + Icur

    eqn0 = Scur - Sprev - h * dSdt(Scur, Icur, beta)
    eqn1 = Icur - Iprev - h * dIdt(Scur, Icur, beta, gamma)

    return eqn0, eqn1


T = infected_data.shape[0]


class SimulateDE(tt.Op):
    itypes = [tt.dscalar, tt.dscalar, tt.dscalar, tt.dscalar]
    otypes = [tt.dmatrix]

    tsteps = range(T)

    def perform(self, node, inputs, output):
        s0, i0, beta, gamma, = inputs[0], inputs[1], inputs[2], inputs[3]
        for i in self.tsteps:
            if i == 0:
                si = np.array((s0, i0)).reshape(1, -1)

            else:
                prev = si[-1]
                nxt = fsolve(bkwd_euler, (100, 100), (prev, beta, gamma, 1/7))
                si = np.vstack((si, nxt))

        output[0][0] = si

    def grad(self, inputs, g):
        # this is just a placeholder, because I cannot
        # figure out how grad() should work in this case
        return [g[0][0], g[0][1], g[0][2], g[0][3]]
```

The issue I'm stuck with now is that I simply cannot figure out what grad() should be in this case, as by my thinking I should simply be able to pass `g` through as I have; gibberish result, but I cannot see why it shouldn't run. But alas, it does not:

```py
theano.config.compute_test_value = 'ignore'
theano.tests.unittest_tools.verify_grad(SimulateDE(), [np.array(100.), np.array(1.), np.array(10.), np.array(1.)])

 <snip>

NotImplementedError: ('input nd\nApply node that caused the error: InplaceDimShuffle{x,0}(<__main__.SimulateDE object at 0x7fdcec9594d0>.0)\nToposort index: 1\nInputs types: [TensorType(float64, vector)]\nInputs shapes: [(45, 2)]\nInputs strides: [(16, 8)]\nInputs values: [\'not shown\']\nOutputs clients: [[Elemwise{mul,no_inplace}(random_projection, InplaceDimShuffle{x,0}.0)]]\n\nBacktrace when the node is created(use Theano flag traceback.limit=N to make it longer):\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2886, in _run_cell\n    return runner(coro)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/async_helpers.py", line 68, in _pseudo_sync_runner\n    coro.send(None)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3063, in run_cell_async\n    interactivity=interactivity, compiler=compiler, result=result)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3254, in run_ast_nodes\n    if (await self.run_code(code, result,  async_=asy)):\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 3331, in run_code\n    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)\n  File "<ipython-input-108-a997c24f1e9a>", line 2, in <module>\n    theano.tests.unittest_tools.verify_grad(SimulateDE(), [np.array(100.), np.array(1.), np.array(10.), np.array(1.)])\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/theano/tests/unittest_tools.py", line 92, in verify_grad\n    T.verify_grad(op, pt, n_tests, rng, *args, **kwargs)\n  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/theano/gradient.py", line 1759, in verify_grad\n    cost = theano.tensor.sum(t_r * o_output)\n\nHINT: Use the Theano flag \'exception_verbosity=high\' for a debugprint and storage map footprint of this apply node.', '\nThe error happened with the following inputs:', [array(100.), array(1.), array(10.), array(1.)], '\nThe value of eps is:', None, '\nThe out_type is:', None)
```

So that `grad()` seems to be getting upset about the fact that the output of `bkwd_euler` is a (45, 2) array, maybe? From what I can understand from the docs, the output of `grad()` should be a 4-dimensional vector since 4 scalar inputs, so not sure what the problem is at this point.

Any help still greatly appreciated!

Comment: Perhaps you want to look into [writing custom Theano Ops](https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/blackbox_external_likelihood.html).

Comment: Have tried going down that road (seems the most likely to work) but the problem is still that I'm having trouble implementing the iteration operation, which is required in this instance owing to the need to simulate the differential equation. Not saying it won't work, I think you're quite correct, just am having trouble pulling it off is all.